# Conditional probability using Bayes's theorem

Tags: conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

From Blitzstein, *Introduction to Probability* (2019 2 edn), Chapter 2, Exercise 25, p 87.

> 25. A crime is committed by one of two suspects, A and B. Initially, there is equal
>     evidence against both of them. In further investigation at the crime scene, it is
>     found that the guilty party had a blood type found in 10% of the population.
>     Suspect A does match this blood type, whereas the blood type of Suspect B is
>     unknown.
>
> (a) Given this new information, what is the probability that A is the guilty
> party?

So here is my approach. Let $A$ stands for "A guilty", $G$ for "Individual having the rare matching blood type" and $B$ for "B is guilty". Then using Baye's theorem
$$P(A|G)P(G) = P(G|A)P(A)$$
$$P(A|G) = \frac{1 * \frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{10}} = \frac{10}{2}$$
Clearly I did something wrong. The solution replaced P(G) with $(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{10})$.

Why am I wrong in saying P(G) is simply $\frac{1}{10}$ because it is the unconditional probability of anybody in the general population having guilty blood type? What did I miss here?

Comment: Seems language needs correction. 10% should be blood type of guilty given its B.

Comment: $P(G)=P(G|A)P(A)+P(G|\lnot A)P(\lnot A)= 1(\frac{1}{2})+ \frac{1}{10}(\frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{20}=\frac{11}{20}$

Comment: Remember that we are told $A$ has the rare blood type so $P(G|A)=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For sake of simplicity, call the blood type $O$.

We should first compute the probability that blood type $O$ is observed at the scene. Given that $A$ is guilty, the probability that blood type $O$ is observed is $1$. Otherwise, given that $B$ is guilty, because their blood type is unknown, there is a $\frac{1}{10}$ probability that blood type $O$ is observed. Since our prior assigns $\frac{1}{2}$ to both suspects $A, B$, then the probability of the evidence is $\frac{1}{2} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{10} \right) = \frac{11}{20}$.

Therefore, the probability that $A$ is guilty increases to $\frac{\frac{1}{2} (1)}{\frac{11}{20}} = \boxed{\frac{10}{11}}$. This makes sense because the blood type is not common.

Comment: Thanks @K.Jiang. I am having difficulty ruling out why P(O) = P(G) is not $\frac{1}{10}$ and why one has to estimate it again using LOTP. It is clearly given that population has 10% incidence rate of having this blood type.

Comment: @Gerry It is because we *know* that $A$ has the rare blood type. This is information that we must use in our calculation of $P (G)$. Consider another case where $A$'s blood type is also unknown. Then, indeed, $P (G) = \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) \left( \frac{1}{10} \right) + \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) \left( \frac{1}{10} \right) = \frac{1}{10}$. The fact that we know $A$ has the rare blood type (and given our prior) makes the probability of observing that blood type more likely.

Answer (score 0):

$P(G_A|B_p) = \frac{P(G_A) \times P(B_p|G_A)}{P(G_A) \times P(B_p|G_A) +  P(\neg G_A) \times P(B_p|\neg G_A)}$

$P(G_A|B_p) = \frac{0.5 \times 1}{0.5 \times  P(B_p|G_A) + 0.5 \times P(B_p|\neg G_A)}$⁰⁰

$G_A$ = $A$ is guilty
$P(B_p)$ = Blood test is positive

We have what's known as *prevalence* = $10 \%  = \frac{1}{10} = 0.1$

Then there's the blood test itself. Tests have properties, pertinent to the answer, and they are *sensitivity* (the fraction of those with the blood group in question it reports as positive) and *specificity* (the fraction of those that don't have the blood group ($0.9$) it reports as negative). *Vide supra* the *denominator*.

In short, the probability of A having the incriminating  blood group *isn't* $10 \%$. It's $P(G_A) \times P(B_p|G_A) +  P(\neg G_A) \times P(B_p|\neg G_A) = \text{denominator}$.
That is to say we need info on how, *sensu latissimo*, **reliable** the blood test is.

In this case $\text{denominator} > 0.5 \iff P(B_p|G_A) = 1$